# How can i fix bootstrap input-group overflow in col-xs-*?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I tried to use an input-group in this website i build. In col-md-* and col-lg-* it behave properly. But when in col-xs-* it's overflowing the container like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YV8V0.png)

Can anybody help me with this problem?

The code:

```
<div class="row" style="border:1px solid #c1c1c1">
    <form>
        <div class="form-group col-xs-5 col-md-3" style="padding:8px;">
            <label for="dari">blah</label>
            <input type="date" class="form-control" id="dari"/>
        </div>
        <style>
            @media(min-width: 992px){
                .col-md-1.stripe{
                    width: 1%;
                }
            }
            .col-xs-1.stripe{
                width: 1%;
            }
        </style>
        <div class="form-group col-xs-1 col-md-1 stripe" style="margin-top:2em; padding:8px;">
            <p><strong>-</strong></p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-5 col-md-3" style="padding:8px;">
            <label for="sampai">blah</label>
            <div class="input-group">
                <input type="date" class="form-control" id="sampai"/>
                <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <button class="btn btn-default">
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i>
                        <span>&nbsp Search</span>
                    </button>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: try adding this css rule to .input-group{max-width:100%}

Comment: can you provide a link or jsfiddle please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example, you can solve it using

```
display: inline-block;
max-width: 100%;
```

using on `input-group`..

In example i added inline style on second input-group and you can see difference between yours and new one.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="row" style="border:1px solid #c1c1c1"> 
  <div class="col-xs-7" style="border: 1px solid #ccc;"><div class="row">
    <form>
        <div class="form-group col-xs-5 col-md-3" style="padding:8px;">
            <label for="dari">blah</label>
            <input type="date" class="form-control" id="dari"/>
        </div>
        <style>
            @media(min-width: 992px){
                .col-md-1.stripe{
                    width: 1%;
                }
            }
            .col-xs-1.stripe{
                width: 1%;
            }
        </style>
        <div class="form-group col-xs-1 col-md-1 stripe" style="margin-top:2em; padding:8px;">
            <p><strong>-</strong></p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-5 col-md-3" style="padding:8px;">
            <label for="sampai">blah</label>
            <div class="input-group">
                <input type="date" class="form-control" id="sampai"/>
                <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <button class="btn btn-default">
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i>
                        <span>&nbsp Search</span>
                    </button>
                </span>
            </div>
            
            <div class="input-group" style="display: inline-block; max-width: 100%;">
                <input type="date" class="form-control" id="sampai"/>
                <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <button class="btn btn-default">
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i>
                        <span>&nbsp Search</span>
                    </button>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
    </div></div>
</div>
```

Also i would suggest you to use `col-xs-12` for larger columns on mobile, and `hidden-xs` for hidding the dash between.